# Example where $X$ and $Z$ are correlated, $Y$ and $Z$ are correlated, but $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Tags: correlation, covariance, independence, intuition

$X,Y,Z$ are random variables. How to construct an example when $X$ and $Z$ are correlated, $Y$ and $Z$ are correlated, but $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: A good example is given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498040/is-this-possible-that-corx-y-0-99-cory-z-0-99-but-corx-z-0

Answer (score 49):

Intuitive example: $Z = X + Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are any two independent random variables with finite nonzero variance.

Comment: Or for that matter $Z=\max\{X,Y\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin That is not guaranteed to work unless the supports of $X$ and $Y$ overlap

Comment: @henry Nice point. But you don't even need them to overlap. Just that there exist values in $X$ which are smaller than some values in $Y$ and vice versa. E.g. discontinuous piece wise functions with no overlap can work.

Comment: @DaleC - When I said "overlap" I meant that the minimum of each was less than the maximum of the other.

Comment: A narrative example: two small kids from a soccer team trying to sneak into a movie by one sitting on the shoulders of the other and wearing a trench coat. Z is the height of the "man"; X and Y are the heights of the kids

Answer (score 7):

Roll two dice.

X is the number on the first die, Z is the sum of the two dice, Y is the number on the second die

X and Z are correlated, Y and Z are correlated, but X and Y are completely independent.

(This is a concrete instance of the answer given by fblundun, but I came up with it before seeing their answer.)